# How to center the map view when I select and load new custom map tiles?

Tags: javascript, web-mapping, google-maps-api

How to center the map view when I select and load new custom map tiles?

I have made a simple web UI where I select date of maps and it will show it tiles, but the problem is, it will not zoom and change map view center to the map tiles latest location. In short I cannot get the lat long of the loaded map tiles.

```
    function toggleOverlay(element) {

      if (element.value == "none") {
        map.overlayMapTypes.clear();
        map.setCenter({ lat: 16.9754250079185, lng: 121.77948420178662 });

        return;
      }

      var path = "/" + element.value + "/"

      imageMapType = new google.maps.ImageMapType({
        getTileUrl: function (coord, zoom) {

          /*if (zoom < 15)
                      if (zoom < 17 || zoom > 20 ||
                        bounds[zoom][0][0] > coord.x || coord.x > bounds[zoom][0][1] ||
                        bounds[zoom][1][0] > coord.y || coord.y > bounds[zoom][1][1]) {
                        return null;
                      }*/

          var myX = coord.x;
          var myY = coord.y;

          return path + '/' + zoom + '/' + myX + '/' + myY + '.png';

          //mapObject.getZoom(22)

        },
        tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256)

      });

      map.overlayMapTypes.clear();
      map.overlayMapTypes.push(imageMapType);

      map.getCenter();
      var mylat = map.getCenter().lat();
      var mylng = map.getCenter().lng();
      map.setCenter({ lat: 16.82554423155411, lng: 121.45481799835964 });

    }
```